# Can you write a Console app with Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

Is it possible to build a console app with Quarkus? In other words, its doesn’t start up a web service but simply run from start to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible currently but that's on our roadmap.

It won't be for 1.3 but maybe 1.4 or 1.5 (so in a month or two).

Comment: Great news thanks. Once that it in place, I will move a fair number of apps to Quarkus